# Virtual Directory Not Created - Azure Bot

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, botframework

I am developing a bot in Azure using the Bot Framework (C#). After spinning it up on Azure I downloaded the source code and tried to open the provided Visual Studio solution file but got an error

```
Creation of virtual directory http://localhost:3894/ failed with the error: Filename: redirection.config Error cannot read configuration file
```

Google points towards an issue with IIS or IISExpress but the recommended solutions (forcing IIS to recreate config files by renaming them) didn't work. I don't know if the issue is with Visual Studio, my system, or something else entirely but anything that could shine light on the situation would be appreciated.

EDIT: Deleted and Re-downloaded both VS and IISExpress, did not fix the problem

Comment: Have you tried opening Visual Studio with elevated privileges ? You can also try copying all files from C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer to C:\Users\v-erdahl\Documents\IISExpress\config then start Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click your project in solution explorer and select properties.  The select web on the left side.  click the create virtual directory button.  see if that works for you.

[image]